# Some symbols are not displayed correctly on the help page "How do I search?" on an international site

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, international-sites

In SOja's "[How do I search?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)", in the explanation about "wild card", some `*` have disappeared.

[Bug report on SO.ja meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3077)

---

**On SOja:** https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching

[image]

**On SO:** https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

[image]

Comment: It looks like this got fixed at some point, so I've marked this as [status-completed].

Comment: @V2Blast I still see what OP shared, maybe it's browser thing. I have Chrome latest on Windows 10.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: Here's what I see on SOja's searching help page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsSEv.png

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't understand the bug before.